# detecting a component click in a custom listview item

Tags: android

I Have a ListView. In my listview I create a custom items on every rows. this custom item as some textviews and two buttons. The problem I have now is I want to detect when the user clicks on the buttons in the listview items.
    But My code is not working.

Please don't mind the numerouse text views that are to be hidden from the user only one is to be seen by the user and the two buttons are visible.

Each time I click the button nothing happens, no response
My listview custom item is pasted below.

Thanks for reading my post, am also grateful for your time and effort.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/listitemdesign"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemprescrip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:visibility="gone"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/agerange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemanufac"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemexdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemdcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemnafno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drugID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

       <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" 
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />


          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       </LinearLayout>

       <View android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="@color/wine" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ordernow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebackground"
        android:src="@drawable/ordernow" 

        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/detailsicon"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/whitebackground"
         />
    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

My activity code is also pasted below. The OnItemClickListener of the ListView component, is what is below :

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemclickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                String drugID = null,drugName = null, drugPrecription = null, drugManufacturedate = null, drugExpiratorydate = null,drugCode = null, nafdacNo=null,drugageRange = null;

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {


                    drugID = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.drugID)).getText().toString();
                    drugName = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemname)).getText().toString();
                     drugPrecription =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemprescrip)).getText().toString();
                    drugManufacturedate = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemanufac)).getText().toString();
                    drugExpiratorydate = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemexdate)).getText().toString();
                     drugCode = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.itemdcode)).getText().toString();
                     nafdacNo = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName)).getText().toString();
                    drugageRange = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.agerange)).getText().toString();

                    orderButton = (ImageButton)parent.getChildAt(9);//view.findViewById(R.id.ordernow);
                    detailsButton = (ImageButton)parent.getChildAt(0);//view.findViewById(R.id.details);

                    Object o = orderButton.getClass();
                    Toast.makeText(context, o.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //Now we are going check for the button that would clicked
                    //int elementID = view.getId();

                    //this.detectItemClicked(elementID);
}
```

Comment: Pls any idea on the above question

Comment: Pls if anyone thinks I should give more explanations, kindly inform me so I do. Thanks alot.